# Samba share on Debian not showing newly created files

Tags: samba

On Debian Squeeze, I have a drive mounted (formatted ntfs) under samba.

While it seems to act generally fine, if a Windows client (Windows 7) creates a new file or folder on it (as opposed to copying one over from the local machine), that file does not appear until the user refreshes the folder window, whereupon they can then name the file in the usual way. This does not happen with Mac clients, which show the new file immediately.

Does anyone know what I can do about this?

Comment: whats the details, What OS is serving the share? is the share name the same as the folder name?

Comment: The OS is GNU/Linux, the distro is Debian and the version is Squeeze. The share name is in upper case, the folder name is in lower case, but otherwise they are the same, yes.

Comment: Try changing the share name as I've seen this before, since case is Irelavant in smb it could fix your issue.

Comment: Wow! That did it! Thanks Steve (BTW I've got all your movies - my favourite is the Man With Two Brains)

Comment: Aww man you have no idea how many Steve Martin quotes i get in a day glad it helped